How to correctly return a CRON String or Expression from a function in a Jenkins file?
I was trying to find a way to choose the cron expression for the triggers block in a Jenkins file, based on the Environment (Development, Test, Prod)
I found this on Stack Overflow: Condition in Jenkins pipeline on the triggers directive
The ticked solution helped me formulate how to setup my own code. However whenever I run the code I have created, I get the following error:
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.split(String)" because "format" is null
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:111)
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:99)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger.<init>(Trigger.java:179)
    at hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.<init>(TimerTrigger.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)

Here is the code that I have been playing around with locally on Jenkins in the pipeline script box:
pipeline {
    agent any
    triggers{
        cron( cronExpression = getCronParams() )
    }
...

And the function in question that is below my pipeline block is:
def getCronParams() {
    withFolderProperties {
        echo "Environment is ${env.ENVIRONMENT}"
        switch ("${env.ENVIRONMENT}") {
            case 'Development':
               echo "Applying Development Area Configuration..."
                return "@midnight"
            case 'Production':
                echo "Applying Production Configuration..."
                return "@midnight"
            default:
                echo "Unknown Environment, unable to handle Environment appropriately, will exit here..."
                break
        }
    }
}

Note: I am using the Jenkins plugin Folder Properties to set the Environment variable.
Here is the complete output of a run using the above code:
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] withFolderProperties
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
Environment is Development
[Pipeline] echo
Applying Development Area Configuration...
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withFolderProperties
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.split(String)" because "format" is null
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:111)
    at hudson.scheduler.CronTabList.create(CronTabList.java:99)
    at hudson.triggers.Trigger.<init>(Trigger.java:179)
    at hudson.triggers.TimerTrigger.<init>(TimerTrigger.java:57)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ProxyException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

(I can provide the complete thread dump if asked but I believe the portion above is the problem.)
Can someone please help explain why a CRON string/expression is being returned as null? What am I missing here?
Update:
I have udpated the switch statement to the below in order to ensure a String is returned with every case of the switch statement:
switch ("${env.ENVIRONMENT}") {
            case 'Development':
               echo "Applying Development Area Configuration..."
                return "@midnight"
            case 'Production':
                echo "Applying Production Configuration..."
                return "@midnight"
            default:
                echo "Unknown Environment, unable to handle Environment appropriately, will exit here..."
                return "@midnight"
                break
        }

I am unfortunately still getting the same error.

I don't think the log is from the code you posted. Where is the output for echo "Environment is ${env.ENVIRONMENT}"? Other strings mismatch too... If I had to guess you are not returning any string in some of the switch branches. Like here:
            default:
                echo "Unknown Environment, unable to handle Environment appropriately, will exit here..."
                break

The last command is echo and it returns null, which becomes the implicit return value.

Hi, thanks for the reply. I have edited the output of the run as you correctly pointed out, I copied in the wrong output log. The output above now includes the line echo "Environment is ${env.ENVIRONMENT}"

I have updated the question to include a return in the default case as well. I get the same error unfortunately.
Thank you for pointing out the implicit return value with the echo. I will experiment with this and see if I can ensure an explicit return. I will update if this solves it.
